# Viewing flagged emails in Outlook (Hotmail)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, hotmail

Is there a way to see all your flagged emails in web Outlook (Hotmail)? I can't find any view or filter that does this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your picture, click the empty space in your search email.
2. A drop down menu shown, click flagged:

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

In your search you should be able to select one of the filters by selecting the search Icon (including: All, Unread, To me, or Flagged). The default filter is All.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use instant search. I have found this from Microsoft

> Instant Search can be used to find flagged items within the selected folder or across all mail folders.
>
> On the Home tab, in the Find group, click Filter E-mail, and then click Flagged.
>
> Sort the Sent Items folder
>
> You can quickly sort your Sent Items folder to display all flagged items together. Do one of the following:
>
> In multi-line view, click Arranged by, and then click Flag: Start Date or Flag: Due Date.
>   In single-line view, click the Flag Status column header.
>   Search in your Sent Items folder
>   You can refine a search for flagged responses by using additional criteria — the message subject or sender.
>
> Open the Sent Items folder, right-click the flagged message that you want to search, point to Find Related, and then click Messages in This Conversation or Messages from Sender.

Hope this helps.

Comment: These instructions are for Office Outlook- not the web version

Comment: @Yarin Yes, I agree, that is a valid point

Answer (score 0):

I have Outlook Mail (Preview) in the Chrome browser. Click on the apps symbol (3x3 squares) at the top left. Click on Outlook Tasks. This shows all (I think) flagged items. Apparently it thinks they're tasks.

Comment: there you can see only part of flagged items (e.g. where due date is set), but not all of them.

Comment: This does not work - clicking on Tasks just goes to Microsoft ToDos